# Seder Tannaim v’Amoraim in English?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally

Is there an English translation of *Seder Tannaim v’Amoraim*?

If so, where may I purchase or read it online?

Comment: Seems unlikely to me to exist. Most Rishonim are not available in english, especially obscure ones like this. Do you have some reason to think it does exist in translation?

Comment: @DoubleAA I have no reason to believe a translation exists, but I thought I'd ask in case there is one